# Need help adding some JavaScript code into my wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Hello I have this script here and I need to put that in my current wordpress theme, but I am confused with the enqueue part.  I know I have to save the hoverintent javascript in my themes library, do I also save the functions javascript in my themes library? Sorry if I did not clarify enough, comment if this is confusing please!

```
jsfiddle.net/ctLevz8L/59/
```

Comment: I fixed your JS Fiddle link and added the code from he fiddle

Comment: the easiest way and to do this would find the right js file to append this block of code you have is to fire up firebug. launch your wp site preferably in Firefox and launch firebug. While its loading open the sources dialog and look at the corresponding js files that are being loaded. select the file that you think is appropriate (theme related js files), locate where it is on the web server and open up the file and add your block of js code.

Comment: if you're doing these types of addition, i'd highly recommend you use git to source control your wp instance.

Answer (score 1):

Take the javascript from your fiddle and save that to `wp-content/themes/mytheme/js/hoverintent.js`.

Then, add the following to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function enqueue_hoverintent {
    //Add the script and jquery-ui to the generated header.
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my_hoverintent', 
         get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/hoverintent.js', 
         array('jquery-ui-core')
    );

    //Add the jqueryui css file from Google's CDN since it isn't included with WP
    wp_enqueue_style (
        'googlecdn_jqueryui_style',
         'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css',
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_hoverintent' );
```

Comment: A `wp_enqueue_` function called on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action automagically adds this to the header in Wordpress.